# io.spring.guides run the task to generate the domain classes based on the WSDL

Tags: spring

I am following this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) and trying to understand the following note:

> All of these chunks of code, the io.spring.guides classes will report
>   compile-time errors in your IDE unless you have run the task to
>   generate the domain classes based on the WSDL.

I want my xsd schema turn into POJO classes. Which task should I run to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and executed `mvn clean install`